# Are there any code coverage analysis tools for Intersystems Cache object script?

Tags: testing, intersystems-cache

If there is some sort of debugging API that would allow someone to write his own code coverage analysis tools that would be acceptable as well.  I don't believe this is a poll question because the exhaustive list of such tools is probably quite small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no readymade coverage tools (afaik). However, you might be able to utilize the MONLBL facilities ([here](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCM_monlbl#GCM_C136592)). These were introduced to be able to identify performance hotspots. 
It would be interesting to look into the code of these, as the necessary hooks to create a code coverage tool are quite similar to the ones you need to create the performance monitoring. If you have access to the WRC I strongly recommend to raise this with ISC, it definitely sounds like something many people could use!
HTH

edit: come to think of it, since monlbl gives you the # of times a line is executed, it's a code coverage with benefits ;) So, the answer is: yes, there are

Answer (score 1):

debuging in Cache' Studio. 
there is also [^PERFMON](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCM_perfmon#GCM_perfmon_using)